Delimiter character inside the dataset but as character not delimiter
I asked this a few days ago, and the answers of the users solved it:
Separate a column in different columns depending on a label
One of the steps on the solution was to use ":" as delimiter; The problem is that the dataset I am using has some ":" in the string that are not a delimiter. For example:
F: Function1; F: Function2; P: proccess1; P: UTP:proccess2

The approach the users suggested me was ok, but it doesnt work with this particular case, I obtain an error, when I want to obtain the string "UTP:proccess2". How could I solve it? Is a very large dataset so is hard to know where are this entries.
I was thinking about modify the dataset, but I am not sure how to do it.
Thank you in advance!!
I tried this, as 1 user suggested me:
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Name, ~Value, ~GOs,
  "Ab1", "1000", "F: f1; F: f2; P: p1",
  "Bb1", "2000", "P: p1; F: f1",
  "Cb1", "3000", "C: c1; F: f1"
)

df |> 
  separate_longer_delim(GOs, delim = ";") |> 
  separate_wider_delim(GOs, delim = ":", names_sep = ":") |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), str_squish)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = `GOs:1`, values_from = `GOs:2`) |> 
  unnest(c("F", "P", "C"))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   Name  Value F     P     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 Ab1   1000  f1    p1    <NA> 
#> 2 Ab1   1000  f2    p1    <NA> 
#> 3 Bb1   2000  f1    p1    <NA> 
#> 4 Cb1   3000  f1    <NA>  c1

I obtained this error:
Error in separate_wider_delim():
! Expected 3 pieces in each element of GOs.
! 9 values were too short.

Can you please show an example where it doesn't work, similar to your tidyverse data frame?

You could use ": " as separator to overcome this (and not need to trim lag/lead spaces).
(example adding in “UTP:proccess2” to reproduce your error)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Name, ~Value, ~GOs,
  "Ab1", "1000", "F: f1; F: f2; P: UTP:proccess2",
  "Bb1", "2000", "P: p1; F: f1",
  "Cb1", "3000", "C: c1; F: f1"
)

df |> 
  separate_longer_delim(GOs, delim = "; ") |> 
  separate_wider_delim(GOs, delim = ": ", names_sep = ":") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = `GOs:1`, values_from = `GOs:2`, values_fn = list) |> 
  unnest(c("F", "P", "C"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   Name  Value F     P             C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>         <chr>
#> 1 Ab1   1000  f1    UTP:proccess2 <NA> 
#> 2 Ab1   1000  f2    UTP:proccess2 <NA> 
#> 3 Bb1   2000  f1    p1            <NA> 
#> 4 Cb1   3000  f1    <NA>          c1

Here’s an alternative solution using separate_wider_regex to detect the first F, P or C and the values after “:”
df |>
  separate_longer_delim(GOs, delim = "; ") |>
  separate_wider_regex(GOs, c(cat = "(?:F|P|C)", ": ", val = ".*")) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = cat,
    values_from = val,
    values_fill = list("-"),
    values_fn = list
  ) |>
  unnest(c("F", "P", "C"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   Name  Value F     P             C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>         <chr>
#> 1 Ab1   1000  f1    UTP:proccess2 -    
#> 2 Ab1   1000  f2    UTP:proccess2 -    
#> 3 Bb1   2000  f1    p1            -    
#> 4 Cb1   3000  f1    -             c1


This take will deal with any label (F, C, P, G, Z etc):
library(tidyverse)

# -----------------
# Toy data
df <- tribble(
  ~Name, ~Value, ~GOs,
  "Ab1", "1000", "F: f1; F: f2; P: UTP:proccess2; Z1: z88",
  "Bb1", "2000", "P: p1; F: f1; Z1: z99; C: c:proccess7",
  "Cb1", "3000", "C: c1; F: f1")

# The code
df <- df %>% 
  separate_rows(GOs, sep = ";\\s+") %>% 
  transmute(
    Name, Value,
    go_names = str_extract(GOs, "^\\w+?(?=:)"),
    go_values = str_remove(GOs, "^\\w+:\\s+"))

# ..any label
df <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = go_names, values_from = go_values, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest_longer(all_of(unique(df$go_names)), keep_empty = TRUE)

The output:
> df
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  Name  Value F     P             Z1    C          
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>         <chr> <chr>      
1 Ab1   1000  f1    UTP:proccess2 z88   NA         
2 Ab1   1000  f2    UTP:proccess2 z88   NA         
3 Bb1   2000  f1    p1            z99   c:proccess7
4 Cb1   3000  f1    NA            NA    c1 

